# Microsoft Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vba

I posted this question before hand to no avail.  I built a table on SQL to get tagnames that I want to pull into Visual Basic. From Visual Basic I wrote a public function to pull my tagnames as string. I then wrote a public sub to pull the tag values from the OPC that's feeding FactoryTalk. I'm now on "This Display" where I dump the combine the code to work together. I can not get it to work properly where it starts "0 to UBound. It's pulling the tagnames from the SQL database.  But on the next command, I am getting "Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set".  I'm not sure what else I'm suppose to define or set with my code.  Any help to get it to work will be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub GetCommsOKTValues()
    Dim HMITagGroup As TagGroup
    Dim HMITag As Tag
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim astrtagNames() As String
    Dim GetCommsOKTag As String
    Dim avarValues() As Variant

    astrtagNames = GetCommsOKTags

    With HMITagGroup
      For intIndex = 0 To UBound(astrtagNames)
        Set HMITag = .Item(astrtagNames(intIndex))

        avarValues(intIndex) = HMITag.Value
      Next
    End With

    Set HMITag = Nothing

    Exit Sub

    ErrHandler:

    Call UltimaLogMessage("VBA Error in modFTVTagFunctions.GetTagGroupValues - Err#" & Err.Number & "          - " & Err.Description & ", Tagname = " & astrtagNames(intIndex))
    Resume Next
End Sub


Public Function GetCommsOKTags() As String()
    ' This function returns an array of tagnames used to define the CommsOK.
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As New Recordset
    Dim dbConn As New Connection
    Dim tagNames() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    ' Make a connection to the database.
    With dbConn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        Call .Open(DBConnString)
    End With

    ' Setup the query for the recipe Values.
    strSQL = "SELECT TagName FROM CommsOKTags"

    Call rs.Open(strSQL, dbConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly)

    ' Make sure there were some records.
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        ReDim tagNames(rs.RecordCount - 1) As String
        i = 0
        Do
            tagNames(i) = rs("TagName")
            rs.MoveNext
            i = i + 1
        Loop Until rs.EOF
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    dbConn.Close
    Set dbConn = Nothing

    GetCommsOKTags = tagNames

    Exit Function

    ErrHandler:

     Call MsgBox("An error occured while getting recipe tags -" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & " - " &     
     Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly)
     Call UltimaLogMessage("modDBFunctions.GetCommsOKTags failed! " & Err.Number & " - " &   
    Err.Description)
     GetCommsOKTags = tagNames
End Function
```

Comment: Where is DBConnString defined?  Does it have the correct value?

Comment: There are questions on the first time you posted this that weren't answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787353/calling-a-sub-for-vba

Comment: Hi czuroski, the DBConnString is defined in a module and it works since this is an existing display that's been on the floor for years.  What I'm doing now is adding code to capture the tagnames and values for this particular display so I can manipulate things easier. But it appears that I am not defining or forgetting to set something.

Comment: Hi Rowland Shaw, I looked it up and it is VB6.5.  I am new to this so it appears that I should not have tagged it as VBA.  Sorry.

Comment: Yes, RossC, you are correct and that is why I am re-posting it in hopes that I may get some guidance.

Comment: Please edit your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HMITag lookup loop, you will get an error if there is no object for the current tag.  You need to detect this condition and handle it (you will have to decide what to do with a missing or invalid tag).

This code will avoid the error that you are getting

```
Dim HMITagGroup As TagGroup 'here it is declared, but not assigned anything'
Dim HMITag As Tag
Dim i As Integer
Dim intIndex As Integer
Dim astrtagNames() As String
Dim GetCommsOKTag As String
Dim avarValues() As Variant

astrtagNames = GetCommsOKTags

'HMITagGroup must be assigned to something or you are guaranteed to get a missing object error'
Set HMITagGroup = ???

With HMITagGroup
   For intIndex = 0 To UBound(astrtagNames)
       If Not .Item(astrtagNames(intIndex) Is Nothing Then
          Set HMITag = .Item(astrtagNames(intIndex))
          avarValues(intIndex) = HMITag.Value
       Else
          'astrtagNames(intIndex) does not have a matching HMITagGroup.Item'
          'The original code was not handling this condition.'
          'You might want to log the name of this tag, and see why there is no HMITagGroup.Item.'
       End If
   Next
End With
```

Comment: Hi, tgolisch, thanks for your input about the error.  That was going to be my next step.  I am still getting the "Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set". Would you happen to know how I can fix this?

Comment: Wait a second.  After looking over your code, I see that HMITagGroup has never been assigned a value.  Yes, that would certainly trigger a missing object reference error.

Comment: Should I set it as.... Set HMITagGroup = Nothing?  Not sure since the tags are coming from SQL Database.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Two lines later, you are referring to HMITagGroup and then using its .item property.  Certainly if it is Nothing, then it won't have a .item property and it will still fail.  I have no idea what your code is supposed to do, but I am certain that you are missing a very important line of code (or two), which should create your HMITagGroup object (and populate it).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, tgolisch, I'll see what I can figure out with the information you gave me when I go into work Monday.  What I'm trying to do is point the tag values (coming in from the OPC into FactoryTalk) to the tag names that will be coming in from the SQL database.  Then we will look to see which tag names didn't have a value attached to it.

Comment: Then write a code to block FactoryTalk from trying to read that tag name without the value. The reason we are trying to get FactoryTalk not to see that tagname is because some of the devices out in the field have been turned off so no value is being sent back to the OPC. So when the user tries to load or save a new recipe on "The Recipe" display", the HMI locks up. I am an E.E. intern so this is new grounds for me with all this code. Again, thanks, tgolisch!